# byte.TryParse() which approach is better

Tags: c#

I just need to advice to make sure which approach is better

1)

```
byte flag = 2; 
byte.TryParse(strFlag, out flag);
```

2)

```
byte flag; 
if (!byte.TryParse(strFlag, out flag)) 
{ 
    flag = 2; 
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What was hard in trying the both approach and seeing the difference?

Comment: I think you can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to see the complier generated code. However, it's not 100% right, just see what happen. For me, compiler will cover the same as in both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want to set `flag` to 2 if `TryParse` fails.

The first approach is wrong. If it fails, it will overwrite your value with 0 (as that is the default value of the `byte` type). You should use the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it'd be approach #2.

The reason is that #1 will overwrite the value of your variable with the default value of the type (in this case 0)

Answer (score 1):

`TryParse` will do the following in your example:

- If `strFlag` is a valid `byte`, decode it and set `flag` to it. Return `true`.
- Otherwise set `flag` to `0` and return `false`.

Note that this means that `flag` will **always** be set by `TryParse`.

If you want `flag` to be `2` in the default case you will need to use the later syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The second.

Once you pass an `out` parameter to a method, the method can do anything it wants to it.

Comment: Righ, but the documentation often states how the method behaves, like in this case: if there is an error output 0.

Answer (score 0):

**2 different things**

in the latter you have a zone of : "what will i do if it will fail"

in the former you don't have it. - it will override the value with default value.

Comment: @Pragmateek still , there is no contradiction. the second one has a code block for "not succeeded" while the former does not.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to point out that there was an hidden issue because the OP wants a default value and seems to believe both were semantically equivalent. Your fixed answer is better now :)